# Macro reader for #+

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying to write a formatting program for Common Lisp code, for which I need to tweak the behavior of the reader, e.g. with a reader macro for comments. Currently looking at #+ e.g.

```
(defun args ()
  #+CCL CCL:*UNPROCESSED-COMMAND-LINE-ARGUMENTS*
  #+SBCL (cdr *posix-argv*))
```

Default reader behavior is to discard the currently inactive branch entirely, but for my purposes I need to keep both. I think that means I need a reader macro for #+.

But # is also a prefix to lots of other things. How can I write a reader macro that handles #+ while keeping the default behavior for # everything else?

Comment: Sharpsign is a dispatch macro character, see http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set__1.htm

Comment: There is a built-in pretty printer: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_b.htm

Comment: @Svante the built in pretty printer mostly doesn’t work for printing syntax with eg #+ in it.

Answer (score 1):

The # character is a dispatch macro character, meaning you can define a reader macro for the #+ combination without affecting any other reader macros beginning with hash.
You can start from the code below, and customize it to do what you want it to:

```
;; define the reader function
(defun custom-comment-reader-macro (stream char &optional num)
  ;; char will be #\+ in our case, and num will be nil.
  ;; stream will be the code input stream
  (declare (ignore char num))
  ;; this is the default behaviour of #+, you can customize it below
  (if (member (intern (string (read stream)) :keyword)
              *features*)
      (read stream)
      (progn (read stream)              ;ignore next token
             (values))))                ;return nothing

;; tell the reader to use our function when it encounters #+
(set-dispatch-macro-character #\# #\+ #'custom-comment-reader-macro)
```